# if statement fails when used after semi-colon separator

Tags: python, if-statement, semicolon-inference

I don't understand why I'm having an error with Python when I use a single-line `if` statement after a semicolon (used as a statement separator).

This is ok:

```
if True: print("it works")
#### it works
```

But this gives a syntax error:

```
a=1; if True: print("it should work?")
#### SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I use Python3, with Spyder.

Thanks for any explanation!

Comment: This doesn't work with any [compound statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html) as the clause header needs to be on it's own line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Semicolons can only be used to join "small statements", which don't include `if` statements. From https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html:

```
stmt: simple_stmt | compound_stmt
simple_stmt: small_stmt (';' small_stmt)* [';'] NEWLINE
small_stmt: (expr_stmt | del_stmt | pass_stmt | flow_stmt |
             import_stmt | global_stmt | nonlocal_stmt | assert_stmt)

[...]
compound_stmt: if_stmt | [...]
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that!

Comment: Clearly, something like `if foo: x=1; y=2` is ambiguous given Python's use of indentation. I suspect there's no ambiguity in `a=1; if True: print("it should work")`. However, it probably isn't worth complicating the grammar to support it. (Or it might not be possible given Python's self-imposed constraint of using an LL(1) grammar.)